# How does FB login for mobile apps with server-side databases work?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile

How does the FB login for mobile apps with server-side databases work?

Tinder is a good example. You sign in with FB through the app, but it clearly needs to do create a user server-side for you where the server-side app has lots of data about you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you successfully login to Facebook on the client you can prompt the client to enter a username or ask the permission to get the email that will be used to uniquely identify the user in your database among other info you may need.

See [Implementation Examples](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.4) for iOS.